# Requests stream timeout not working for given website

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I have the following function that pulls down the content from the home page of domains. But it doesn't work for the site http://mywatchedmovies.com.

```
import requests

def fetch_url(url, timeout, max_content, headers):

    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, timeout=timeout, headers=headers)
    r.raise_for_status()

    if int(r.headers.get('Content-Length',0)) > max_content:
        raise ValueError('response too large')

    content = r.raw.read(max_content+1, decode_content=True)
    if len(content) > max_content:
        print(url)
        raise ValueError('Too large a response')
    return {'url':url,'content':content,'status_code':r.status_code}

timeout = 10
max_content = 5000000
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}

fetch_url('http://mywatchedmovies.com', timeout, max_content, headers)
```

If I alter the function to just get the `head` then it triggers the timeout which is good. But I need this function to be very high performance and would rather not fetch the head then pull down the homepage. Or can I do this with requests without performance decrease?

Answer (score 0):

Please take my response with a grain of salt, I am not a requests expert.

Requesting just the head with timeout flag must be faster because the size of the head is very small in case the server is not responding or is taking too long to download as opposed to making one request.get() and getting stuck in a long response.
Even though you will have to make a subsequent request for the home page download the previous requests for headers would already have filtered out problematic servers.

To request only the head.

```
r = requests.head(url, timeout=1)
```